# Restarting program in debug mode

Tags: java, exec, debug-mode

I am trying to restart  a java program in debug mode using this code

```
public static final String SUN_JAVA_COMMAND = "sun.java.command";

public static void restartApplication() throws IOException 
{
    try 
    {
        String java = System.getProperty("java.home") + "/bin/java";
        final StringBuffer cmd = new StringBuffer("\"" + java + "\" ");
        String[] mainCommand = System.getProperty(SUN_JAVA_COMMAND).split(" ");

        if (mainCommand[0].endsWith(".jar")) 
        {
            cmd.append("-jar " + new File(mainCommand[0]).getPath());
        } 
        else 
        {
            cmd.append("-cp \"" + System.getProperty("java.class.path") + "\" " + mainCommand[0]);
        }

        cmd.append("");

        for (int i = 1; i < mainCommand.length; i++) 
        {
            cmd.append(" ");
            cmd.append(mainCommand[i]);
        }

        cmd.append(" -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000");
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd.toString());
        System.exit(0);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        throw new IOException("Error while trying to restart the application", e);
    }
}
```

However each time the application starts from this main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    boolean isDebug = java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getInputArguments().toString().indexOf("-agentlib:jdwp") > 0;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, isDebug);
    Utility.restartApplication();
}
```

The joptionpane always displays the message false why wont this work

Is the problem in the isDebug or with the restart application;  I think the problem is the restart.

Answer (score 0):

Your `isDebug` right-hand-side seems to be sufficiently tricky to not be sure whether it should work or not. Why don't you just set it to `true` and test whether the debugger starts. Afterwards you known whether it's the `isDebug` evaluation or the debugger restart.

Comment: Hmmm, last time I tried this was a decade ago and I still feel the pain. Write yourself a nice batch file / shell script and fiddle with it until the debugger start and then create your Java code to mimic the batch file / shell script,